# How should I test if an object is a XML document (in a cross browser way)

Tags: javascript, xml

For an unit test, I want to be able to check if a certain returned object is a XML document. What is the best way to do so?

I am currently just testing for `doc.implementation` (the first DOM property that came to mind) but is there a better way? Also, is there a nice way to tell apart XML documents from HTML documents?

Comment: `doc.doctype` is the doctype node. The doctype node should be XHTML rather then html.

Comment: My documents aren't XHTML so they have no doctype. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isXML(xmlStr){
  var parseXml;

  if (typeof window.DOMParser != "undefined") {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
      return (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    };
  } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" && new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
      var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async = "false";
      xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
      return xmlDoc;
    };
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  try {
    parseXml(xmlStr);
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;      
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is no longer working.
DOMParser does not throw an exception.
It just returns an xml tree with error description. Maybe it will change in the future/it will be fixed.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45566

Comment: And this is a possible solution, to check for "parseerror" node in the output
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70824527/2258851

Answer (score 3):

I'd have a look at the implementation of [jQuery.isXMLDoc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isXMLDoc/) for ideas. It turns out that the code itself is in the Sizzle library, [here](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/2e664828f3e0a17d70ef4bf69322e06da04eb406/sizzle.js#L1407):

```
Sizzle.isXML = function( elem ) {
    // documentElement is verified for cases where it doesn't yet exist
    // (such as loading iframes in IE - #4833) 
    var documentElement = (elem ? elem.ownerDocument || elem : 0).documentElement;

    return documentElement ? documentElement.nodeName !== "HTML" : false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're currently doing an implementation similar to http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/getxml3.shtml

If that's the case, I know it's not pretty but couldn't you simply just wrap it in try/catch?  Or, do you need to know if it is XML and specifically not some other type.  If that's the case I'm not sure you can without making some other assertions.  A try catch will at least allow you to create an XML document from an object without throwing an error to the screen.  You could assume then that if it loads into the DOM that it IS valid XML.

Comment: This is for writing an **unit test**. I need to be able to check if a certain function that is supposed to return a XML document actualy does so.