# Regex to find overlapping, randomly-named tags -- non-greedy backreference

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a generated HTML string that may contain overlapping tags, and trying to find them to make the HTML valid. The string is in the format (ex: overlapping tags, then nested tags):

`<tag_1> xx <tag_2> xx </tag_1> xx </tag_2> xx <tag_1> xx <tag_3> xx </tag_3> </tag_1>`

I want to extract only `<tag_1> xx <tag_2> xx </tag_1>`

and NOT

`<tag_1> xx <tag_3> xx </tag_3> </tag_1>`

-

Currently, my regex matches both cases.

I'm assuming I need a regex that non-greedily matches a back-reference (\1) to the tag name... here's what I have, I can't figure out that last part. Is that possible in javascript?

`/<tag_([A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>.*?<tag.*?<\/tag_\1>/gi;`

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure regex is the right tool for that.

Comment: I'm sure regex is not the right tool for that.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's the best tool or not, the question may still have a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Noone said it hasn't.

Comment: isn't "<tag_2> xx </tag_1>" invalid?

Comment: Use an xml parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563554/how-do-i-detect-xml-parsing-errors-when-using-javascripts-domparser-in-a-cross

Comment: btoueg Won't an XML parser bork? He's trying to find properties of invalid XML.

Comment: Are you working with XML or HTML?  Do you need to handle minimized tags (NETs)?  What *precisely* is meant by "overlapping tags"?

Comment: I'm working with HTML not XML - I'm just creating custom tags, since the tag name is irrelevant and I'm just using it to assign CSS to a span.... Checking needs to be fast - it will occur on each keystroke, so I'd like this check to be on the order of 10ms or so. I need to use some tool to generate valid HTML, while preserving the general content of the HTML string. In this case, I'd like to catch the invalid overlapping tags, and note that the relevant span is tied to both tag_1 and tag_2... so something like: `<tag_1> xx </tag_1><tag_1_2> xx </tag_1_2><tag_2> xx </tag_2>`

Comment: I'm essentially generating a HTML string from a simple string by splicing in tags at the relevant locations. I need the HTML to be valid, while preserving the information meant to be captured by the overlapping tags. The use case is that it is a genetic sequence, and I'm annotating it with genetic 'features' which map to specific locations. I want the string to be editable, and I figure the best way to quickly handle changes is to not capture the location of input and alter the hash of locations of each annotation, but to alter the string directly, and pull out the annotations when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
/<tag_([A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>.*?<tag_([A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>[^\/]*?(?!(\/tag_\2))\/tag_\1>/gi
```

for your sting

```
<tag_1> xx <tag_2> xx </tag_1> xx </tag_2> xx <tag_1> xx <tag_3> xx </tag_3> </tag_1>
```

it will match

```
<tag_1> xx <tag_2> xx </tag_1>
```

but not

```
<tag_1> xx <tag_3> xx </tag_3> </tag_1>
```

check [here](http://regex101.com/r/aR6rB2)

Comment: It will also not match something like this: `<tag_1> xx <tag_3> xx <tag_4> xx </tag_4> </tag_1>`

Comment: @ExpertSystem yes, regex will only check a specified level deep(in op's post seems only one level deep nest), if `<tag_1> xx <tag_3> xx <tag_4> xx </tag_4> </tag_1>` is also a case to check, i think regex won't give any solution.

Comment: poorly worded question so my bad, dont like leaving questions unaccepted... works for what I asked i suppose