# How to check if DOM Parser was successful

Tags: javascript, parsing, dom, domparser

```
function $(selector) {

    var resultObject = {
        append: function (element) {

          var parser = new DOMParser();
           var dos = parser.parseFromString(element, "text/html");

          if (dos.getElementsByTagName("parsererror ").length == 0)
            {
                alert("SUCESS");
            }
            else
                alert("Error occured while parsing!")

        }
    }
    return resultObject;
}
```

Call:

```
    <input type="button" value="append tag/text " onclick="$('.testing').append('<ul><li>yeah</li></ul>');" />
```

How can I check if my input was valid, because in my function I only check If the tag parseerror exists. Is it possible to check if the parsing was successful without checking after the tag, because if I check the tag it always return that it was successfull...?

Comment: ["Note that if the parsing process failed, DOMParser currently does not throw an exception, but instead returns an error document (see bug 45566):"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Error_handling)

Comment: @PeeHaa see edit..... How can I check if this "parseerror" Tag exists?

Comment: Maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563554/how-do-i-detect-xml-parsing-errors-when-using-javascripts-domparser-in-a-cross/11623204#11623204 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563554/how-do-i-detect-xml-parsing-errors-when-using-javascripts-domparser-in-a-cross/20294226#20294226

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect XML parsing errors when using Javascript's DOMParser in a cross-browser way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563554/how-do-i-detect-xml-parsing-errors-when-using-javascripts-domparser-in-a-cross)