# Check if AJAX response is [object XMLDocument]

Tags: javascript, ajax

I interact with an API via AJAX, and upon evaluation of the response some other steps will follow.

The response can be either `-1`, `1`, `0`, `some error message, ie "Please provide a custom field name."`, and `[object XMLDocument]`

A successful response is considered only the XML one. The problem is I don't know how to check that...

What's the correct `if` check to evaluate that?

```
  if (response === <what?>) {
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672597/how-should-i-test-if-an-object-is-a-xml-document-in-a-cross-browser-way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I test if an object is a XML document (in a cross browser way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672597/how-should-i-test-if-an-object-is-a-xml-document-in-a-cross-browser-way)

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work... It returns an error, but not to a specific line. XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: http://*******************
Line Number 1, Column 1: